# Como faço para rotacionar um imagem com jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

Bom é o seguinte eu tenho o seguinte código:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
</head>


<img src="roda.png"></img>

<button>Rodar!</button>
```

Pretendo fazer com que ao clicar no button Rodar, que a imagem rotacione, de forme a girar, como é demonstrado no seguinte site: www.csgo500.com

Como poderei fazer isso?

Obrigado.

Comment: jquery rotate: https://code.google.com/archive/p/jquery-rotate/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Podes usar o `transform: rotate(7deg);` para isso e fazer `transition: transform 2s;` para ficar com rotação suave.

```js
var btn = document.querySelector('button');
var img = document.querySelector('img');

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var graus = Math.random() * 1000;
  img.style.transform = 'rotate(' + graus + 'deg)';
});
```

```css
img {
  transition: transform 2s;
}
```

```html
<button type="button">Rodar!</button>
<img src="http://www.pngall.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/Compass-Free-PNG-Image.png"></img>
```

Comment: Muito bom Sergio +1

Comment: Como faço, para que a imagem, rode apenas com o sentido dos ponteiros do relogio?

Comment: @Gonçalo isso tem a ver com os graus que dás. No meu exemplo ele sorteia entre 0 e 1000 graus. Se em vez de sortear somares então já faz o que queres.